# how can I see functions of AngularJs and JS and suggestions in autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intellij-idea

I am developing Java applications in IntelliJ and I am a java developer basically,
But I had to write the client-side code with AngularJs and javascript, Is there a way that I coding in Intellij AngularJs and JS like Java, in fact, I would like to autocomplete my code for functions and services and etc in Intellij.

Comment: Try using visual studio code https://code.visualstudio.com/ adding extension which might help you or you can use https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Intellij for both Java and AngularJs.

You just have to install the [AngularJs plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6971-angularjs) :

In File → Settings, click on Plugins and search for AngularJs[image]

Then you'll have autocompletion.